# Invoke Keycloak SPI action from a custom page

Tags: java, keycloak

I have 3 different application that uses keycloak for authentication and authorization.
all three apps are having different domain names, however the authentication will happen on only one keycloak (keycloak is shared between all three apps). We have developed an SPI to handle email OTP authentication (send OTP and Validate OTP).
All 3 apps will have OTP based login ONLY. How will we invoke the action of SPI from a custom page (and not keycloak page)?